# Gradle force download a different version only for a particular Transitive dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am `force-downloading` a dependency using the below gradle-script

```
implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.2.2.RELEASE') {
        force = true
}
```

This dependency always brings me `3.2.13.RELEASE` version of `io.projectreactor:reactor-core` (transitive dependency)

But i want to have `3.3.0.RELEASE` of `io.projectreactor:reactor-core`

Below is my full `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.7'
}





apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.SR3'
        mavenBom 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:2.1.1.RELEASE'
        mavenBom  org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'

    //security
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'


    //other
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'


}
```

How to force download only this particular dependency in gradle ?

Comment: Is it possible to post the rest of the `build.gradle`? An empty project with just a dependency to `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.2.2.RELEASE` pulls in `io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.3.1.RELEASE`.

Comment: It seems you have some other dependency which is referring to `3.2.13.RELEASE`  version of `io.projectreactor:reactor-core`

Comment: added my latest `build.gradle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [resolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) like:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.3.0.RELEASE'
    }
}
```